# Function for echo only the image's src attributum's value from a string

Tags: php, function, preg-match, image

I'd like to create a function, that echos only the image links from a string.

My code fails, but i don't know why.

```
function csak_a_kepek($bejovo_szoveg){
    $re = '/(?<=src=")(?:.*?)(?=")/ui';
    $eredmeny = preg_match('/(<img[^>]+>)/i', $bejovo_szoveg, $matches);
    for($i=0;$i<count($matches);$i++){
        $nMatches = preg_match($re, $matches[$i], $aMatches);
    }
    for($i=0;$i<count($aMatches);$i++){
        $return .= $aMatches[$i].'/;/';
    }
    return $return;
}
```

the /;/ is a delimiter, to make it easier to explode it.

Can you help me please, where am i have to change it, to make it work?

The working code:(thanks for redskins80)

```
include('simplehtmldom/simple_html_dom.php');
function only_pictures($string){
    $html = str_get_html($string);
    foreach($html->find('img') as $element) {
      $return .= $element->src . '<br />';
    }
    return $return;
}
```

Comment: Ugh, will people ever start using english in their code even if it's not their native language? And is there any reason why you a) don't use a DOM parser instead of regexes and b) **return a string to be split later instead of an array**?

Comment: use simple_html_dom to parse all html. Parsing HTML using regexes isnt recommended. With DOM you can easily scrape tags out and also specify what part of the tags you want!

Comment: your simple_html_dom solution looks good, i'm on to make it workable for me :D Please wait 5 minutes :)

Comment: are you allergic to foreach loops >.<

Comment: I've tried to implement the simple_html_dom Parser, but it fails: Fatal error: Call to undefined function mb_detect_encoding() in D:\[FOLDER_NAME]\simplehtmldom\simple_html_dom.php on line 988

Comment: I've changed to an older version of it (1.11), and it works! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Your patterns seems to be wrong. Try this:

```
$html = '<img class="" src="http://www.google.com" />';
$pattern = '/<img([^>]*)>/i';
preg_match($pattern, $html, $m);

if(!empty($m)) {
    $max = count($m);
    for($i=1; $i<$max; $i++) {
        $pattern = '/src="([^"]*)"/i';
        preg_match($pattern, $m[$i], $m2);
        echo $m2[1]."\n";
    }
}
```